# how to boot into windows from grub rescue?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

everyone.

I used to have linux mint 15 , ubuntu, and windows 7 dualbooted on my *samsung E300*.

I did so using the following video: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HpUgIkl4oFA

Afterwards, after installing an audio through hdmi thing, a bug was coming in my terminal. So I went to windows and deleted all the tiny partitions. the only remaining things were system, C disk and D disk.

After rebooting, I get the following error:

```
Error: no such partition.
Grub rescue>_
```

How can I boot into windows and more importantly, how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the Windows 7 CD/DVD you have and choose the repair option when asked. No problems will be found, but when asked select 'command prompt' and then enter the following

bootrec/fixmbr
bootrec/fixboot

Give your machine a reboot and hey presto, you're back to booting straight into Windows without GRUB.